# Iterate over all the elements in a list to find the row indexes in a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dataframe

I have the following list:

```
list=[24,136,308,514,527,658,1002,1070,1560]
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
df:
        co_stkdate  Code  ab-ret    
0       1997-07-02  11     NaN  
1       1997-07-04  11     NaN  
2       1997-07-07  28     NaN  
3       1997-07-08  28     0.002376 
4       1997-07-10  30     NaN  
... ... ... ... ...
5595    2002-11-13  5067   -0.001146
5596    2002-11-14  5067    0.051200    
5597    2002-11-15  5121    0.092791    
5598    2002-11-18  5121    0.044851    
5599    2002-11-20  5121    0.035072
```

I want to find the rows in `df` which have indexes same as the elements given in `'list'` and find 10 rows above and below those specific rows in `df` for each of those rows and print them with all the column values and store them in a dictionary with co_stkdate as key. Hence I tried the following code:

```
values={}
for elem in list:
  values = df.iloc[(elem - 10): (elem +10), elem]
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

How can it be done? Guidance on how to remove the error will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
elm = [24,136,308,514,527,658,1002,1070,1560]
values = {}
for index in elm:
    values[index] = df.loc[(list(range(index-10, index+11))),:]
```